# Get substring of a string after the first occurrence of a character

Tags: string, go

In Golang, I am trying to get a substring of a string after the first "-" in the string. The string used may or may not contain multiple occurrences of "-", and the string prior to the first "-" is unknown at the moment.

For instance

```
hello-world -> world
hello-world-hello -> world-hello
```

Would cutting it by `strings.Split` and then recombining it be the best way or is there a simpler, quicker way?